IntelliJ cannot access class from local Maven dependency
I created a brand new Maven project, added a dependency from jar file using <scope>provided</scope>.
When I try to use one specific class from the jar IntelliJ highlights it red and says it doesn't exist while all other classes from same package work.
In project explorer it shows as KonquestDiplomacyType.class instead of just KonquestDiplomacyType.
Why could it be happening? How can I fix it?
Details:
Project's Java version set to 21, said jar file is from Java 11 I believe.
IntelliJ: 2022.2.1 (Community Edition), build #IC-222.3739.54
The dependency jar: https://github.com/Rumsfield/konquest/releases/download/v1.6.0/konquest-api-1.6.0.jar
The class in question: com.github.rumsfield.konquest.api.model.KonquestDiplomacyType
Pictures:


Whole pom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>eu.testGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.rumsfield</groupId>
            <artifactId>Konquest</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/dependencies/Konquest-api-1.6.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

I tried restarting IntelliJ, invalidating caches, starting a new completely blank project, changing Java versions, re-downloading the jar file and using alternative jar file (full jar instead of just API).
I also tried to look at the class with JavaDecompilerGUI but it just shows // INTERNAL ERROR // which makes me think maybe there is something wrong with the class even though IntelliJ can decompile it fine.

Did you try using a different version of the dependency? Can you try using the class in your code and running mvn clean compile? What is the output of that?

@dan1st Yes, "cannot find symbol" pointing at line with KonquestDiplomacyType a;

Did you import the type as well when doing that? What happens with different versions of the dependency?

In the first screenshot you can see no-import use of the class - still red. From older versions 1.4.3 works, where 1.5.0 has "Updated JDK to version 21" in patch notes, maybe it's related

What happens with an import (or by specifying the full type name) using mvn clean compile (not viewing the errors in IntelliJ)? With different versions, I meant choosing a different version (not 1.6.0) from https://github.com/Rumsfield/konquest/releases/.

did you try to install the file into your local maven repository and access it as usual, that means no provided scope?
